# Pass an ArrayList<Place> to another activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList of nearby places from my MainActivity to a second activity, the problem is the class Place defined by Google is not serializable, and the app crash when changing windows. Is there a way to bypass this problem without creating my own Place class?

```
private ArrayList<Place> nearbyPlaces;

button_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(nearbyPlaces.size() > 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaceList.class);
                intent.putExtra("nearbyPlaces", nearbyPlaces);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                debugMessage("No establishment to show");
            }
        }
    });
```

The error :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzas@17b4ae0

Comment: `ArrayList` does not implement `Parcelable` which is a requirement to put it as extra

Comment: It really is the Place class that is not parcelable :
putParcelableArrayListExtra
(String,
java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>)
in Intent cannot be applied
to
(String,
java.util.ArrayList<com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place>)

Comment: Indeed, that makes more sense